# Prove the uniform convergence of series in a compact space

Tags: sequences-and-series, compactness

I have to prove that if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{|a_n|}$ converges, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x-a_n}$ converges absolutely and uniformly in any compact space that $\forall n \in \mathbb N$ doesn't contain point $x=a_n$.

Since there is a compact space and all functions $\frac{1}{x-a_n}$ are continuous on it, maybe it's worth to use Dini's theorem, but I can't figure out how to apply it, because I need to show that this series converges pointwise in this compact space.

Comment: Not Dini, you don't know whether the convergence is monotonic (and if the $a_n$ are complex numbers, monotonic generally doesn't even make sense). Use the Weierstraß test. Can you find a lower bound for $\lvert x-a_n\rvert$ in terms of $\lvert a_n\rvert$ for large $n$?

Comment: I just see that $|x - a_n| \ge ||x| - |a_n||$

Comment: Good start. Now, for large $n$, you know that $\lvert a_n\rvert$ also must be large, otherwise $\sum \frac{1}{\lvert a_n\rvert}$ wouldn't be finite. So, since $x$ lies in some compact set $K$, what can you say about $\lvert x\rvert$?

Comment: We can say that $A \le |x| \le B$ for some $A,B$.

Comment: We only need $\lvert x\rvert \leqslant B$. Now, is there an $n_0$ such that for $n\geqslant n_0$ you have $\lvert a_n\rvert \geqslant 2B$, say?

Comment: And we get $|x - a_n| \ge |B|$ and $\frac{1}{|x-a_n|} \le \frac{1}{|B|}$ for all $x \in K$ and $n \ge n_0$.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't help, unfortunately. Can you find $\lvert a_n\rvert - B \geqslant f(\lvert a_n\rvert)$?

Comment: Do you mean $|a_n| - B \ge \frac 12 |a_n|$?

Comment: Yes. So you get $\left\lvert\frac{1}{x-a_n}\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{2}{\lvert a_n\rvert}$ for large enough $n$. See how it's finished?

Comment: Yeah, I see now. Thank you very much.